# Cannot stop jupyterhub in Docker?

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, cmd, jupyterhub

So, I have Docker installed on Windows 10. Then, in `cmd.exe`, I run a docker container:

```
C:\Users\user>docker start -i image_name
```

... containing an Ubuntu 20.04 image, where, once started, from the command line I run:

```
$ jupyterhub -f /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
```

So, this has been running for three days without a problem; then I start noticing some problems, I though I should restart jupyterhub, and ... I just realized when I hit CTRL-C in the `cmd.exe` window which hosts the jupyterhub Docker image -- which otherwise stops jupyterhub and makes it exit -- now is completely ignored!

So, how could I stop jupyterhub when it is stuck in a Docker image running in `cmd.exe` in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I did - from another `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\Users\user>docker kill image_name
```

Note this killed the entire docker process in the original `cmd.exe` window (not just the jupyterhub inside). Then from the original `cmd.exe` window:

```
C:\Users\sd>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND       CREATED       STATUS                        PORTS     NAMES
4f2b0875216a   ubuntu-20-jup   "/bin/bash"   2 weeks ago   Exited (137) 19 seconds ago             image_name
```

Note it has bad exit state (137) - but it can be started again:

```
C:\Users\user>docker start -i image_name
```

... and inside `ps -axf` confirms jupyterhub is not running - so it can be started again via the same command line as in the OP, and it seems to work.